# Use PHP Library

Tags: php, html

I have found the following PHP library which seems to fit my needs for comparing HTML: https://github.com/caxy/php-htmldiff

Unfortunately I do not have any clue how to wrap this thing into my one of my projects. This is what I tried:

```
include('./HtmlDiff.php');


if(isset($_GET['old']) && $_GET['new']){

  $oldUrl = $_GET['old'];
  $newUrl = $_GET['new'];

  $oldContent = getHttpsContent($oldUrl);
  $newContent = getHttpsContent($newUrl);

  $diff = new HtmlDiff( $oldContent, $newContent );
  echo $diff->build();

}else{
  echo "Please provide an old and new GET-Parameter containing the URLs of the pages to be compared.";
}


function getHttpsContent($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $response;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Caxy\HtmlDiff\AbstractDiff' not found in Caxy\HtmlDiff\HtmlDiff.php on line 10
```

I suppose this is caused by the fact that it uses namespaces and I think that this could be resolved by using composer. At least thats the only thing I saw mentioned in the installation instructions, since I have no clue about inclusion of PHP libraries myself. I looked at the Composer site and downloaded it but it seems to be the case that you have to install it on the dev-server to use it, which is not possible for me.

Can someone please assist me on using this library?

Comment: Install using composer and then load the composer autoloader

Comment: _Can someone please assist me on using this library..._ I see on thi s github project there are a lot of instructions

Comment: So I harrased the system admin to install composer and ran it, now I got this vendor folder with an autoload.php in it. I tried including it but it does not work.

Comment: If only composer had [a manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)